# How do I use different date formats for serialization & deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm getting an object with the date field in the format `2022-02-11` which I'm mapping into an object as follows:

```json
{ "dateTimeField": "2022-02-11" }
```

```java
@Data
class MyPojo {
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateTimeField;
}
```

Now I need to send this object as a json response, but I need it to be in a different format:

```json
{ "dateTimeField": "2022-02-11 00:00:00" }
```

If I change the `pattern` field, deserialization fails:

```java
@Data
class MyPojo {
    // com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2022-02-11": expected format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date dateTimeField;
}
```

How do I use different patterns for serialization & deserialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished using separate annotations on the getter and setter of the field:

```java
@Data
class MyPojo {

    private Date dateTimeField;

    // Used during serialization
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    public Date getDateTimeField() {
        return dateTimeField;
    }

    // Used during deserialization
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    public void setDateTimeField(Date dateTimeField) {
        this.dateTimeField = dateTimeField;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using Lombok's (experimental as of 11 Feb 2022) [onX](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/onX) feature:

```java
@Data
class MyPojo {
    @Getter(onMethod_ = {@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}) // Used during serialization
    @Setter(onMethod_ = {@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")})          // Used during deserialization
    private Date dateTimeField;
}
```